# How to define @Rule and @ClassRule with junit5

Tags: junit5, mockmvc

I want to migrate junit4 to junit5 , And I use @Rule annotations for junit4. Like this:

```
public class A {

@ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();
  @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

}
```

And I want migrate junit5 but I don't know how to change Rule and ClassRule

This is my pom.xml section junit5

```
 <!--junit5-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.vintage.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Only required to run tests in an IDE that bundles an older version -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-migrationsupport</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

How to I use Rule and ClassRule at junit5?

Answer (score 4):

JUnit Jupiter introduces a new extension mechanism. Instead of Rules, you have to use the new `SpringExtension` which is [available in Spring 5](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-junit-jupiter-extension). There's a [backport for Spring 4](https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5) by the original author as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're not using Spring already, you do *not* "*have to* use the new SpringExtension", you can just use the BeforeAllCallback and AfterAllCallback extension APIs in JUnit 5. There's an example [at Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-migration#6-new-test-rules-annotations), about 2/3 of the way down the page. Note that "TestExtensionContext" is now "ExtensionContext".